# Double integral involving the derivative of the Dirac delta function

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, infinity, dirac-delta

Consider the double integral
\begin{equation}
I=\int^\infty_{-\infty}dx\int^\infty_{-\infty}dy f(x)\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\delta(x-y)\right]g(y)
\end{equation}
I'm not sure which of the following two ways to calculate it is the correct one:

1. $I=\int^\infty_{-\infty}dx\int^\infty_{-\infty}dy f(x)\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\delta(x-y)\right]g(y)=\int^\infty_{-\infty}dx\int^\infty_{-\infty}dy f(x)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left[\delta(x-y)g(y)\right]$
   $=\int^\infty_{-\infty}dx f(x)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left[\int^\infty_{-\infty}dy\delta(x-y)g(y)\right]=\int^\infty_{-\infty}dx f(x)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}g(x)$.
2. Using the relation $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\delta(x-y)=-\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\delta(x-y)$ and integrating by part, then
   $I=\int^\infty_{-\infty}dxf(x)\int^\infty_{-\infty}dy \left[-\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\delta(x-y)\right]g(y)$
   $=\int^\infty_{-\infty}dxf(x) \left[-\delta(x-y)g(y)\right]|^{y=\infty}_{y=-\infty}-\int^\infty_{-\infty}dxf(x)\int^\infty_{-\infty}dy \left[-\frac{\partial}{\partial y}g(y)\right]\delta(x-y)$
   $= \left[-f(y)g(y)\right]|^{y=\infty}_{y=-\infty}+\int^\infty_{-\infty}dxf(x)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}g(x)$.

We see that method 2 gives an extra boundary term compared with the result of method 1.

Comment: I was recently very busy and didn't noticed your messages...now I have accetped your answer below, thank you very much for the useful discussions.

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's discuss the object in the original post that is denoted by

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\frac{\partial \delta(x-y)}{\partial x}g(y)\,dy\,dx\tag1$$

We see the presence of the Dirac Delta $\delta$ appearing in this expression.  However, the Dirac Delta is not a function.  Rather, it is a [Generalized Functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_function), also known as a [Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)).

Distributions are linear [Functionals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_(mathematics)) that map test functions in the space $C_C^\infty$ (infinitely differentiable functions with compact support) into numbers.  For the Dirac Delta, the functional definition is given as

$$\langle \delta_a, f\rangle =f(a) $$

where $f\in C_C^\infty$.

Now, the interior integral notation you've used in $(1)$ is only notation.  The object denoted by that interior integral is the linear functional

$$\underbrace{\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\partial \delta(x-y)}{\partial x}g(y)\,dy}_{\text{Notation only}}\equiv \frac{d}{dx}\langle \delta_x,g\rangle =g'(x)$$

where $f\in C_C^\infty$ and $g\in C_C^\infty$.  Therefore we find that

$$\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\frac{d}{dx}\left(\langle \delta_x,g\rangle\right)\,dx&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)g'(x)\,dx\tag2
\end{align}$$

---

---

**ALTERNATIVE DERIVATION**

The distributional derivative of the Dirac Delta (the unit doublet), denoted $\delta_a'$,is defined as

$$\langle \delta_a,f\rangle=-\langle \delta_a,f'\rangle =-f'(a)$$

for any test function $f\in C_C^\infty$.

We could have interpreted the object in $(1)$ to mean

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(y) \langle \delta_y',f \rangle\,dy$$

for both $f$ and $g$ in $C_C^\infty$.

Then, in this case, we have

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(y) \langle \delta_y',f \rangle\,dy=-\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(y) f'(y)\,dy
\tag3$$

whereupon integrating the integral on the right-hand side of $(3)$ by parts with $u=g(y)$ and $v=f(y)$ we find that

$$-\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(y) f'(y)\,dy=-\left.\left(f(y)g(y)\right)\right|_{-\infty}^\infty+\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(y)g'(y)\,dy\tag4$$

Inasmuch as $f$ and $g$ have compact support, they vanish for $|x|>L$ for some $L$ and hence the first term on the right-hand side of $(4)$ is identically $0$.  Hence, replacing the dummy integration variable $y$ with $x$, we find that

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(y) \langle \delta_y',f \rangle\,dy=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)g'(x)\,dx$$

which agrees with the result in $(2)$.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply, Mark. After all one has to use the fact that $f$ and $g$ have compact support and approach $0$ as $|x|\to\infty$. What if $f$ and $g$ do not have compact support? For example, $f(x)=e^{ikx}$ or $e^x$?

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  While $e^{ikx}$ and $e^x$ do not have the proper behavior at $\infty$ to qualify as a standard test function, the distributions $\delta$ and $\delta'$ have compact support on $\{0\}$.  Hence, we can augment a test function outside of $\{0\}$ without altering the resulting value of the functional.  So, for example for the functional $\langle \delta_x,g\rangle $, we can write $\langle \delta_x, h_x g\rangle $ where $h_x(y)=1$ in a neighborhood of $\{x\}$ and has compact support.  Be careful here.  We must require here that $fg'$ is integrable.

Comment: Is it true that for all $f$ and $g$ that make $fg'$ integrable, the boundary term always vanishes?

Comment: No, that is not true.

Answer (score 0):

The Dirac delta and its derivatives only play nice with functions (& distributions) in $C_C^\infty$, and these satisfy$$\lim_{y\to\pm\infty}f(y)=\lim_{y\to\pm\infty}g(y)=0,$$so$$\left.[-\delta(x-y)g(y)]\right|_{y=-\infty}^{y=\infty}=0,\,\left.[-f(y)g(y)]\right|_{y=-\infty}^{y=\infty}=0.$$

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Can I understand like this: all the functions that make $\int^\infty_{-\infty}dx f(x)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}g(x)$ finite must also make $[-f(y)g(y)]|^{y=+\infty}_{y=-\infty}=0$? If so, one can reach a consistency.